# No video until Windows loads

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm working on a retro Windows XP PC, but the hardware is semi-modern; the motherboard is an Intel DQ77KB and the CPU is an i5-3470T. I believe this was close to the last Intel chip with integrated Intel HD graphics that's supported by XP. It's probably also supported by Windows 10.

I used to be able to see the BIOS screen as soon as the PC boots, but after installing the graphics drivers, that stopped, and now there's no video until XP loads.

Looking around the GPU config menus, I suspect that on driver installation, the primary screen got set to the board's LVDS/eDP connector, but once the driver loads up, it either does the right thing or starts mirroring the display. The menus are somewhat inconsistent with what displays are present.

There is a "built-in display"

[image]

It doesn't seem to be an option for the primary display

[image]

I can configure mirroring:

[image]

My goal is to be able to see the BIOS again. Resetting the BIOS doesn't help. The manual states:

> Internal flat panel display settings will not be overwritten by loading BIOS setup defaults.

so this makes sense. I've never been able to get the standard (vs embedded) DisplayPort connector to work, but it might be because the monitor resolution is too high (it's higher than the highest resolution the motherboard docs say is supported). HDMI works, though. I tried a DP to HDMI cable. It worked the same as the HDMI port, and the device was still a "digital television."

My ideas for getting back video are

- Uninstall the video driver and hope it reverts a setting. My fear is I'm left with no video at all.
- Try a PCIe video card
- Are there LVDS to VGA boards?
- See if I happen to get an existing Windows 10 installation to boot and show video, then try configuring the GPU with a modern driver/control panel
- The board has AMT support. Can I gain BIOS access that way, or would I have needed to set it up earlier?
- Maybe DisplayPort will work with a lower resolution monitor, but I don't have one
- Maybe pulling the cr2032 battery for a while will actually reset the settings

Comment: BIOS has nothing to do with drivers. It doesn't use them at all and is not aware of the OS drivers. It just loads the BIOS screen too quickly and immediately just to boot from HDD. RESETTING BIOS or plays with a battery doesn't help. And battery never resets the settings - it's done by jumper. I suggest to disable fast boot in bios and enter a boot delay.

Comment: My theory on the BIOS and drivers was installing (or changing) the driver config changed what the integrated GPU's primary output is. The issue isn't that that BIOS screen loads too quickly; if I hit whichever key brings up the BIOS config or boot menu, I never see any graphics, even after 5 minutes. Ctrl+Alt+Delete worked, Windows booted, and then I got graphics.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of Fast boot mode.

Comment: @Hardoman that makes sense, and my description seems to match fast boot. I wasn't able to find a way that disabled it--or I did, but it didn't fix my problem. I found a doc for a different Intel board that said "hold the power button for 3 seconds" to force entering the BIOS. It didn't fix it, but it showed "t-" (a t and a hyphen) on the screen in text mode. I tried removing the boot device. No luck. I tried moving the "bios setup" jumper to the setting that forces the BIOS to load after POST. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get to the BIOS to show by following instructions intended for an Intel NUC board.

1. With the computer off, hold the power button for 3 seconds. Any shorter and the board will boot normally. Any longer than 4 seconds and the board turns off. If there's a speaker attached, there's a beep for every second that passes (release after 3 beeps).
2. Press F2 to enter the bios. Possibly because of monitor settings, I only saw `t-`. F3 would disable fast boot.

My specific problem was the LVDS panel was enabled, so F3 did nothing, and fast boot was already disabled. I might have enabled it by mistake, or I might be enabled by default. If I hadn't seen more signs of life, I might have assumed the board was dead.